# Using vtkOrientationMarkerWidget with QVTKRenderWindowInteractor [PyQt4/PySide]

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyside, vtk, qvtkwidget

I working on a PySide/vtk GUI using `QVTKRenderWindowInteractor` widget class. 
The widget is working well, unless when I try to add a orientation axis (see image) using `vtkOrientationMarkerWidget`:

```
axesActor = vtk.vtkAxesActor();
axes = vtk.vtkOrientationMarkerWidget()
axes.SetOrientationMarker(axesActor)
axes.SetInteractor(self.iren)
self.ren.AddActor(axesActor)
axes.EnabledOn() # <== application freeze-crash
axes.InteractiveOn()
```

A similar [bug has been already reported for ubuntu](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vtk/+bug/1353984), showing that the bug is reproduced only with [Qt example](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vtk/+bug/1353984/+attachment/4171966/+files/with_qt.py), while the same [example without Qt](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/vtk/+bug/1353984/+attachment/4171970/+files/without_qt.py) works well.

Any solution to this behavior ?
[image]

Comment: instead of using the last two lines, what you could use, you could just use the line `axes.On()`

Comment: Tested with `axes.On()` the window freezes, does it work on your machine ?

Comment: Testing with PySide also gives the same behavior

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Got this answer from Nicholas R. Rypkema :

https://nrr.mit.edu/blog/note-about-vtk-pyqt-and-vtkorientationmarkerwidget

Long story short : this will fix your problem

```
axesActor = vtk.vtkAxesActor();
self.axes = vtk.vtkOrientationMarkerWidget()
self.axes.SetOrientationMarker(axesActor)
self.axes.SetInteractor(self.iren)
self.ren.AddActor(axesActor)
self.axes.EnabledOn() # <== application freeze-crash
self.axes.InteractiveOn()
```

Comment: You should add the essential part from the off-site resource to your answer. Also your code snippet is copypasta from OP's post.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me! The key is to prevent axes to go out of scope by making it a class member (self.axes).

Comment: This solves the problem, as @mululu said, by changing the lifetime of the `vtkOrientationMarkerWidget` instance, by making it a member of the main application class (which subclasses `QtGui.QMainWindow`) where `QVTKRenderWindowInteractor` is defined. Answer accepted !

Comment: I report that this solution also works for solving the same bug when using VTK in C++, i.e. a variable of type vtkSmartPointer<vtkOrientationMarkerWidget> should be made a member of a class that lives for the duration of the VTK loop execution.